# Ubuntu won't Hibernate

Tags: ubuntu, suspend

With my new built computer Ubuntu 10.4 lucid won't hibernate or suspend.  It's a custom-built Core i7 on the Gigabyte X58A-UD3R motherboard. Hibernate is enabled in the bios.

Running `sudo hibernate` gives:

> hibernate:Warning: Tuxonice binary
>   signature file not found. Some modules
>   failed to unload: nvidia hibernate:
>   Aborting suspend due to errors in
>   ModulesUnloadBlacklist (use --force to
>   override).

After installing, linux-generic-tuxonice and linux-headers-generic-tuxonice, and rebuilding my nvidia dev drivers, it still does not work. But I think I'm closer. Now, when I run `sudo hibernate` I get:

```
hibernate: TuxOnIce reported the following errors:
 - TuxOnIce was aborted (see dmesg).
 - Some devices refused to suspend (see dmesg).
```

"gmesg | grep error" returns

```
 [  736.173906] PM: Device usb9 failed to freeze: error -2
 [  736.642208]                  : A device suspend/resume returned an error.
```

Any ideas how to find out what is on usb9 and why it's failing to freeze.  The only thing that I have on usb is the keyboard and mouse.

Comment: can you provide more information please. How do you try to hibernate? And what happens when you do?

Comment: I select hibernate from the menu, it gives a cursor, cursor disappears, then act just as if the screen was locked.  Sorry much more to add by way of details.

Comment: Try running `sudo /sbin/hibernate` from your console. And copy-paste the results in your question ( if it doesn't work ).

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu 64 bit? I'm experiencing a slew of problems on 64bit and nvidia graphics cards.

Comment: yes 64 bit Ubuntu 10.4

Comment: I never got my Fedora machine to hibernate when I had Nvidia (from nvidia.com) drivers. However, it just works perfectly fine when I'm using the inbuilt graphics chipset.

Comment: Works now that I updated to 11.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that this might not help anyone, but it hibernates now that I updated to 11.04 Natty.  I'm still using the Nvidia drivers and all the peripherals are the same.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1430274) you need to have Tuxonice installed. While I'm not entirely sure about this, can you open `synaptic` and look for packages named "tuxonice"? Unfortunately, different posts say different things, so all that I can help is [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hiberate#TuxOnIce).

Good luck :)

Comment: That helps. It appears that the NVIDIA modules are unloading but the it is still not staying in hibernation.  I do get the warning "hibernate:Warning: Tuxonice binary signature file not found."

Comment: even after installing the `tuxonice` packages? then maybe you need to change the kernel

Comment: What a pain that was.  I installed the linux-generic-tuxonice package. Which killed my nvidia drivers. So I had to install the headers and rebuild my NVIDIA drivers.  An hour wasted and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to find out what usb9 refers to. To do this, have a look at /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb9/{product,idProduct,idVendor}, which should help you what particular USB device is refusing to suspend. If it's something you can unplug, try without that.